# How to send array values in a $.get call via jquery?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have multiple text boxes with array names, like:

```
<input type='text' name='test[]' class='test_tb' id='test1' value=''/>
<input type='text' name='test[]' class='test_tb' id='test2' value=''/>
```

Now if I was using a form, I could easily serialize it and send it, but I want to know how to build it manually. I tried something like

```
$.get('test.php',{
   'test[]':$("#test1").val(),
   'test[]':$("#test2").val()
},function(d){
   console.log(d);
});
```

But since a object can't have repeating keys, obviously this didn't work...so what is the manual way of doing this?

PS: This is for learning purpose not any actual task.

Comment: You don't need the form, you can serialize a set of inputs too, just use `$(':text').serialize()`

Comment: @koala_dev I know, but as I said in the question, i was looking for the manual way of doing things just for learning. But thanks for mentioning this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.get('test.php',{
   'test[]':[$("#test1").val(), $("#test2").val()]
},function(d){
   console.log(d);
});
```

Comment: Why the -1? This works as expected, though the `[]` are not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I think Jquery's [map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) is the solution in this case. For a more generic solution, I would recommend using the following approach:

```
var values = $("input[type='text']")
          .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

$.get('test.php', {
   test: values
}, function(d){
   console.log(d);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want array, so make array.

```
$.get('test.php', {
   test: [
     $("#test1").val(),
     $("#test2").val()
   ]
}, function(d){
   console.log(d);
});
```